# If two columns satisfy a condition return calculated value from other columns. Pandas / Windows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: Refer Image]

Refer yellow highlighted cells:

If K = LDE then look for FDE in column J (above LDE's row), in Result column return (D from LDE minus A from FDE) (ie 223-307 = -84)

Refer green highlighted cells: 152-385 = -233 and so on.

How to solve ?

Data:

```
['03-01-2011', 523, 698, 284, 33, 416, 675, 300, 690, 314, '', '', 'FDM', ''] ['27-01-2011', 353, 1, 50, 547, 514, 957, 804, 490, 108, '', 'LDE', '', ''] ['28-01-2011', 307, 837, 656, 755, 792, 568, 119, 439, 943, 'FDE', '', '', ''] ['31-01-2011', 327, 409, 155, 358, 120, 401, 385, 965, 888, '', '', '', 'LDM'] ['01-02-2011', 686, 313, 714, 12, 140, 112, 589, 908, 605, '', '', 'FDM', ''] ['24-02-2011', 161, 846, 816, 223, 387, 566, 435, 567, 36, '', 'LDE', '', ''] ['25-02-2011', 889, 652, 190, 324, 947, 778, 575, 604, 314, 'FDE', '', '', ''] ['28-02-2011', 704, 33, 232, 630, 344, 796, 331, 409, 597, '', '', '', 'LDM'] ['01-03-2011', 592, 148, 974, 540, 848, 393, 505, 699, 315, '', '', 'FDM', ''] ['31-03-2011', 938, 768, 325, 756, 971, 644, 546, 238, 376, '', 'LDE', '', 'LDM'] ['01-04-2011', 385, 298, 654, 655, 2, 112, 960, 306, 477, 'FDE', '', 'FDM', ''] ['28-04-2011', 704, 516, 785, 152, 355, 348, 106, 611, 426, '', 'LDE', '', ''] ['29-04-2011', 753, 719, 776, 826, 756, 370, 660, 536, 903, 'FDE', '', '', 'LDM'] ['02-05-2011', 222, 28, 102, 363, 952, 860, 48, 976, 478, '', '', 'FDM', ''] ['26-05-2011', 361, 588, 866, 884, 809, 662, 801, 843, 668, '', 'LDE', '', '']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a quite tricky solution that works.

```
import pandas as pd

# define groups between two LDE
df['Group'] = (df['K'] == 'LDE').cumsum().shift(1, fill_value=0)

# custom function to perform your subtraction
def f(x):
    if x.loc[x['J'] == 'FDE', 'A'].size == 0:
        return None
    else:
        return x.loc[x['K'] == 'LDE', 'D'].iloc[0] - x.loc[x['J'] == 'FDE', 'A'].iloc[0]

# get list of numerical results
results = df.groupby('Group').apply(f).tolist()

# input the list into the specified LDE rows
df.loc[df['K'] == 'LDE', 'Results'] = results
```

---

Results

[image]

---

Starting data

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['03-01-2011', 523, 698, 284, 33, 416, 675, 300, 690, 314, '', '', 'FDM', ''], ['27-01-2011', 353, 1, 50, 547, 514, 957, 804, 490, 108, '', 'LDE', '', ''],
                   ['28-01-2011', 307, 837, 656, 755, 792, 568, 119, 439, 943, 'FDE', '', '', ''], ['31-01-2011', 327, 409, 155, 358, 120, 401, 385, 965, 888, '', '', '', 'LDM'], ['01-02-2011', 686, 313, 714, 12, 140, 112, 589, 908, 605, '', '', 'FDM', ''], ['24-02-2011', 161, 846, 816, 223, 387, 566, 435, 567, 36, '', 'LDE', '', ''], ['25-02-2011', 889, 652, 190, 324, 947, 778, 575, 604, 314, 'FDE', '', '', ''], ['28-02-2011', 704, 33, 232, 630, 344, 796, 331, 409, 597, '', '', '', 'LDM'], ['01-03-2011', 592, 148, 974, 540, 848, 393, 505, 699, 315, '', '', 'FDM', ''], ['31-03-2011', 938, 768, 325, 756, 971, 644, 546, 238, 376, '', 'LDE', '', 'LDM'], ['01-04-2011', 385, 298, 654, 655, 2, 112, 960, 306, 477, 'FDE', '', 'FDM', ''], ['28-04-2011', 704, 516, 785, 152, 355, 348, 106, 611, 426, '', 'LDE', '', ''], ['29-04-2011', 753, 719, 776, 826, 756, 370, 660, 536, 903, 'FDE', '', '', 'LDM'], ['02-05-2011', 222, 28, 102, 363, 952, 860, 48, 976, 478, '', '', 'FDM', ''], ['26-05-2011', 361, 588, 866, 884, 809, 662, 801, 843, 668, '', 'LDE', '', '']],
                  columns=['Date'] + list(map(chr, range(65, 78))))
```

Answer (score 1):

- ugly but works...
- find rows that contain **FDE** in column **J**
- for each of the rows, find other row you want
- finally do calc and return it

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['03-01-2011', 523, 698, 284, 33, 416, 675, 300, 690, 314, '', '', 'FDM', ''], 
['27-01-2011', 353, 1, 50, 547, 514, 957, 804, 490, 108, '', 'LDE', '', ''] ,
['28-01-2011', 307, 837, 656, 755, 792, 568, 119, 439, 943, 'FDE', '', '', ''], 
['31-01-2011', 327, 409, 155, 358, 120, 401, 385, 965, 888, '', '', '', 'LDM'] ,
['01-02-2011', 686, 313, 714, 12, 140, 112, 589, 908, 605, '', '', 'FDM', ''] ,
['24-02-2011', 161, 846, 816, 223, 387, 566, 435, 567, 36, '', 'LDE', '', ''] ,
['25-02-2011', 889, 652, 190, 324, 947, 778, 575, 604, 314, 'FDE', '', '', ''] ,
['28-02-2011', 704, 33, 232, 630, 344, 796, 331, 409, 597, '', '', '', 'LDM'] ,
['01-03-2011', 592, 148, 974, 540, 848, 393, 505, 699, 315, '', '', 'FDM', ''] ,
['31-03-2011', 938, 768, 325, 756, 971, 644, 546, 238, 376, '', 'LDE', '', 'LDM'], 
['01-04-2011', 385, 298, 654, 655, 2, 112, 960, 306, 477, 'FDE', '', 'FDM', ''] ,
['28-04-2011', 704, 516, 785, 152, 355, 348, 106, 611, 426, '', 'LDE', '', ''] ,
['29-04-2011', 753, 719, 776, 826, 756, 370, 660, 536, 903, 'FDE', '', '', 'LDM'], 
['02-05-2011', 222, 28, 102, 363, 952, 860, 48, 976, 478, '', '', 'FDM', ''] ,
['26-05-2011', 361, 588, 866, 884, 809, 662, 801, 843, 668, '', 'LDE', '', '']], columns=["Date"]+list("ABCDEFGHIJKLM"))

def findandcalc(lde):
    # find last row from begining of DF, to place LDE was found that contains "FDE"
    fde = df.iloc[0:lde.name].loc[lambda d: d["J"].eq("FDE")].tail(1)
    # if row was found do calc and return it
    return np.nan if len(fde)==0 else lde["D"] - fde["A"].values[0]

df.loc[df["K"].eq("LDE"), "Result"] = df.loc[df["K"].eq("LDE")].apply(findandcalc, axis=1)

df
```

#### vectorised solution

- much cleaner....
- filter to rows that have **LDE** or **FDE** in required columns
- test that **FDE** is in previous row, then perform simple calc
- join this series back to dataframe for final result

```
rs = df.loc[df["K"].eq("LDE") | df["J"].eq("FDE")].assign(
    Result=lambda d: np.where(
        d["K"].eq("LDE") & d["J"].shift().eq("FDE"), d["D"] - d["A"].shift(), np.nan
    )
)["Result"]

df.join(rs)
```

| Date | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03-01-2011 | 523 | 698 | 284 | 33 | 416 | 675 | 300 | 690 | 314 |  |  | FDM |  | nan |
| 27-01-2011 | 353 | 1 | 50 | 547 | 514 | 957 | 804 | 490 | 108 |  | LDE |  |  | nan |
| 28-01-2011 | 307 | 837 | 656 | 755 | 792 | 568 | 119 | 439 | 943 | FDE |  |  |  | nan |
| 31-01-2011 | 327 | 409 | 155 | 358 | 120 | 401 | 385 | 965 | 888 |  |  |  | LDM | nan |
| 01-02-2011 | 686 | 313 | 714 | 12 | 140 | 112 | 589 | 908 | 605 |  |  | FDM |  | nan |
| 24-02-2011 | 161 | 846 | 816 | 223 | 387 | 566 | 435 | 567 | 36 |  | LDE |  |  | -84 |
| 25-02-2011 | 889 | 652 | 190 | 324 | 947 | 778 | 575 | 604 | 314 | FDE |  |  |  | nan |
| 28-02-2011 | 704 | 33 | 232 | 630 | 344 | 796 | 331 | 409 | 597 |  |  |  | LDM | nan |
| 01-03-2011 | 592 | 148 | 974 | 540 | 848 | 393 | 505 | 699 | 315 |  |  | FDM |  | nan |
| 31-03-2011 | 938 | 768 | 325 | 756 | 971 | 644 | 546 | 238 | 376 |  | LDE |  | LDM | -133 |
| 01-04-2011 | 385 | 298 | 654 | 655 | 2 | 112 | 960 | 306 | 477 | FDE |  | FDM |  | nan |
| 28-04-2011 | 704 | 516 | 785 | 152 | 355 | 348 | 106 | 611 | 426 |  | LDE |  |  | -233 |
| 29-04-2011 | 753 | 719 | 776 | 826 | 756 | 370 | 660 | 536 | 903 | FDE |  |  | LDM | nan |
| 02-05-2011 | 222 | 28 | 102 | 363 | 952 | 860 | 48 | 976 | 478 |  |  | FDM |  | nan |
| 26-05-2011 | 361 | 588 | 866 | 884 | 809 | 662 | 801 | 843 | 668 |  | LDE |  |  | 131 |